# How can I load an image in Android?

Tags: android

How can I load an image in Android?

Comment: What code have you tried to use to do this?

Comment: Read this site first: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the image as a resource to the project, and then build an `ImageView` that uses that image resource. Check out the details at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html